# How to check the permission for group and other users?

Tags: c

It seems only current user's permission can be checked via `access()`.

(Example: `rwx`).

Generally many file managers (Nautilus, Dolphin, Thunar, PCManFM, emelFM2, etc...) display the permissions for all of three subjects (Example: `rwxr-xr-x`) somehow.

How to check the permission for all of three subjects (user, group, other users)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a the stat function. It returns a structure with the permissions.

> man 2 stat

The structure is also called stat, and includes a protection field st_mode.

Comment: Well... It seems stat.st_mode is octal number that describes permissions for all three subjects and file's type, so I can see these through printf("%o\n", stat.st_mode);. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `stat` - `man 2 stat`